# Junit testing using mockobjects

Tags: java, database, junit, mocking, easymock

I'm trying to wright some test int the first case my test fails, while I know my code works:

```
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class TestGetConnection {
@Test
    public void getConnection() throws SQLException{
    GetConnection getCon = new GetConnection();
    Connection con = getCon.getConnection();
    assertEquals("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@3aa9e816",con.toString());

}
}
```

This is the GetConnectionclass:

```
package BE.Intec.Daniel.BabySteps;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GetConnection {
    private String url2 = "jdbc:mysql://";
    private String url;
    private String user;
    private String timezone = "?useUnicode=true&use  JDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=CET";
    private String password;
    private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public GetConnection() {
    System.out.println("Geef het adres zonder http:// of www. van de database in aub.");
    url2 += input.nextLine();
    url = url2 + timezone;
    System.out.println("Geef de username in aub.");
    user = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Geef het paswoord in aub.");
    password = input.nextLine();

}

public String setUrl(String dbName) {
    url2 += dbName;
    return url = url2 + timezone;
}

public java.sql.Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    }
}
```

In the second test I use a mockobject to get a connection first, but somehow the before dosn't gets excecuted before trying to create the database.

```
package BE.Intec.Daniel.BabySteps;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.easymock.EasyMock;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestCreateDatabase {
    private Connection con;
    @Before
    public void init() throws SQLException{
        GetConnection getcon = EasyMock.createMock(GetConnection.class);
        con = getcon.getConnection();
    }

    @Test
    public void createDatabase(){   
        CreateDataBase newDb = new CreateDataBase(con); 
        String result = newDb.createDataBase();
        assertEquals("Uw databse werd succesvol gecreëerd",result);
        }
   }
```

Here is the CreateDatabaseclass:

```
package BE.Intec.Daniel.BabySteps;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import com.mysql.cj.api.jdbc.Statement;

public class CreateDataBase {
private Connection con;
private java.sql.Statement stat;
private String databaseName;

public CreateDataBase(Connection con) {
    this.con = con;
    createDataBase();
}

public String createDataBase() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Hoe moet uw database noemen?");
    databaseName = in.nextLine();
    String succes = "";
    try {
        stat = con.createStatement();
        String statement = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " + databaseName;
        stat.executeUpdate(statement);
        succes ="Uw databse werd succesvol gecreëerd";
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Er ging iets fout");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return succes;
}

public String getDatabaseName() {
    return databaseName;
}
```

}

Anny ideas why my tests fail?
Anny help would be greatly apriciated
Don't mind my English, I'm Belgian, so not native.

Answer (score 0):

This first test is a technical test. You want to check the driver is correctly configured.

You should stub the String values returned by `scanner.nextLine()` with value (url, username, password), you want to use for your test.
Besides, you should not check `"com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@3aa9e816"` in the `assertEquals()` method. Relying on the default `toString()` method from Object class to assert a result is a bad idea as it contains in its representation the hashcode of the object (`@...` part) that is not a correct way to compare content.
This should be enough :

```
Assert.assertTrue(con.toString().contains("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl"));
```

Here is the updated test method :

```
@Test
public void getConnection() throws SQLException {
    String input = "urlToTest\nuser\nvalue";
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes());
    System.setIn(in);
    GetConnection getCon = new GetConnection();
    Connection con = getCon.getConnection();
    Assert.assertTrue(con.toString().contains("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl"));
}
```

For the second test, you should favor Mockito over EasyMock that is more easy, effective, flexible and powerful to use.
besides, the test logic used is not correct.
Here you mock `GetConnection` object but you don't specify what the mock object should do when methods are invoked on  :

```
@Before
public void init() throws SQLException{
    GetConnection getcon = EasyMock.createMock(GetConnection.class);
    con = getcon.getConnection();
}
```

Anyway mocking in this is probably not the best choice.
`CreateDataBase` class performs database creation.
If  you want to test it, you should rather test it by integration (that is with a real database. Why not a in memory database) rather than using mocks.

Comment: Thanks David, this is verry helpfull. I schould have mentioned this is for a school assignment where we had to wright a program that manages the administration for a companny. Easymock is what they used as example in, the course, that's why I used it. I runed my code, so I know the database creation works, but I have to wright a test for it. We schould try to aim for about 95% testcoverage and I always find  it hard to wright tests for void methodes

Comment: And for the first test. Why the inputStream? Wouldn't:                                            @Test
public void getConnection() throws SQLException {
    GetConnection getCon = new GetConnection();
    Connection con = getCon.getConnection();  Assert.assertTrue(con.toString().contains("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl"));
}                                                                                                                       be enough?

Comment: You are welcome. Unfortunately, at school, we don't study always the things to use... To answer to your question : because in the `GetConnection()` constructor, you have The `Scanner` invocation : `input.nextLine();`. If you don't simulate data for the input, the input and the test will wait for input forever.